# Merging datasets in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I am trying to merge two datasets for table a and table b. It is for longitduinal purposes where I have created time invariant variables such as sex and education type.

```
joinedaandb <- full_join(tbl_df(tablea), tbl_df(tableb), by = "pidp")
```

The unique identifier is pidp. There are a bunch of variables I was expecting to match up such as sex, edtype and age into one variable but instead it has created a sex.x variable and a sex.y variable.

```
pidp        <dbl> 280165, 541285, 541965, 665045, 956765, 987365, 1558565, 1833965, 229…
$ sex.x       <fct> female, male, female, male, male, female, female, male, male, female,…
$ edtype.x    <fct> proxy, proxy, proxy, inapplicable, proxy, proxy, at higher education …
$ age.x       <fct> 32, 25, 23, 29, 56, 21, 18, 46, 36, 17, 29, 22, 28, 57, 20, 33, 27, 6..
```

A bit further down these y variables appear.

```
$ sex.y      : Factor w/ 7 levels "missing","inapplicable",..: 7 6 NA 6 NA NA NA 6 6 NA ...
 $ edtype.y   : Factor w/ 10 levels "missing","inapplicable",..: 3 3 NA 2 NA NA NA 3 3 NA ...
 $ age.y      : Factor w/ 91 levels "missing","inapplicable",..: 23 16 NA 20 NA NA NA 37 26 NA ...
```

What does this mean? And how do I get it so that it matches the variables such as sex from tablea and tableb into a singular variable in the new dataframe.

Cheers

Comment: It's possible you don't really want a `full_join` which explicitly says... **"return all rows and all columns from both x and y"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With joins (merges) you have two options for columns:

- (a) you join on the column---include it in the `by` argument---and the values in each table will be compare and must be equal for the row to be joined
- (b) you don't join on the column---not included in the `by` argument---and no assumptions are made about whether the values are equal. Columns from each data frame will be included separately, and it's up to you to handle them.

> There are a bunch of variables I was expecting to match up

If you want them to be matched, you need to tell your `full_join` call. This means putting them in the `by` to your `full_join`. If you leave the `by` argument blank, `dplyr`'s defaults will assume you want to match all columns with the same names. When you do specify a `by` argument, no more assumptions will be made, and any columns that appear in both data frames but do not appear in the `by` argument will be kept separately, with `.x` and `.y` appended so you can tell the sources apart.